# Problem with optical sizes option in package MinionPro

Tags: fonts, superscripts, minionpro

I have converted the .otf files for Adobe MinionPro to PostScript Type1 files and used the auxiliary files for metrics and encodings provided with the package MinionPro. Everything works fine except for two features. The first is that in the next MWE, which I run under `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[fullfamily,opticals,mathlf,minionint]{MinionPro}

\begin{document}

Testing MinionPro

\[ \phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-x^{2}/2} \]

\end{document}
```

the superscript and supersuperscript faces for the numerals (`2`) do not appear, only their bounding boxes. The issue remains unless I have only `opticals` and `minionint` as options. I want to have the optical sizes selection feature. Besides, although only of secondary importance to me, if I try to use the `openg` option, it happens the same thing when a have a `g` to be typeset in math mode, namely, only the bounding box appears. Is this happening to anyone else? Any possible solution?

Just in case that this may come to someone's mind: yes, in the conversion to Type1 I have started up from the Adobe .otf files which include Caption, Subhead, and Display besides the Text size.

Yet another strange issue is that if I use the original Adobe .otf files under `XeLaTeX`, a kerning seems to be wrong: there is a collision between the glyphs `V`or `W` (uppercase) and  `i` (lowercase). Such a collision does not appear when I use the package MinionPro, even though I got the font outlines from the same .otf files. Anyone else has noticed this?

Comment: Could you try [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro), which might fix your problem? At least the openg issue should be solved, don't know about your major issue, though... It would be interesting to know, which font version you have: use ``otfinfo -v`` for that.

Comment: @sebschub: Thanks for your attention and for pointing out the existence of FontPro. I'll be trying and come back as soon as I have something to say. Regarding the version of my .otf files, this is what I got: Version 2.068;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.57;makeotf.lib2.0.21895